# Get current frame size in surfaceview using FFmpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, height, frame

I want to create an android application with the following steps

1. Have to play a live video - I have done
2. Get the current frame from the video
3. have to find the frame size (height & width)

Using FFmpeg.

If anyone know please help me with this!

Thanks!

Comment: Cool, what question do you have that we can answer?

Comment: @szatmary, How to get the current frame size (height x width) of a video input? Note: not trying to set the frame size, but obtaining the current frame size please.

Comment: Input into what?